# В чем ошибка при создании виджета

Tags: yii2

вот так использую в представлении

```
use frontend\widget\wath\Wath;
<?= Wath::widget(['serial'=>$model,'theSerial'=>0,'class'=>'film']); ?>
```

вот так в самом Wath.php

```
class Wath extends Widget
{
     public $serial;
     public $theSerial;
     public $class;

     public function init()
     {
         parent::init();
     }

     public function run()
     {
         return var_dump($this->class);
     }
}
```

выдает null, а вот если `$this->serial` то выдает то что приходит `'serial'=>$model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз читаю документацию по конфигурации и там указано касательно виджетов:

> Note that because the class name is already given, the configuration array should NOT have the class key.

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#widget-configurations)

Или по-нашему:

> Обратите внимание что параметр class НЕ передается, так как полное имя уже указано.

[Источник](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-configurations.md#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-)

---

В общем виде конфигурация в Yii2 представляет собой массив следующего вида:

```
[
    'class' => 'ClassName',
    'propertyName' => 'propertyValue',
    'on eventName' => $eventHandler,
    'as behaviorName' => $behaviorConfig,
]
```

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#configuration-format)

В случаях конфигурации приложения и виджетов свойство `class` не указывается, так как имя класса уже получено ...

Для приложения во входящем скрипте:

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Для виджета (конкретно для виджета `Menu`):

```
use yii\widgets\Menu;

echo Menu::widget([
    'activateItems' => false,
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
        ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['product/index']],
        ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['site/login'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
    ],
]);
```

---

Иными словами, свойство `class` зарезервировано для внутренних нужд Yii2: для указания класса, экземпляр которого мы хотим создать, сконфигурировать и использовать для чего-либо.